# How to capture Http verb and api end point using AOP in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I am planning to implement an aspect in order to capture the following values for a given rest API on successful return, in my spring boot application:

1. api endpoint i.e. like /api/ ...
2. Http verb. i.e. PUT/POST etc
3. Request payload and request/query param

I am doing this as follows:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

  private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());


  @Pointcut("within(com.web.rest.*)")
  public void applicationResourcePointcut() {
  }

  @AfterReturning(value = ("applicationResourcePointcut()"),
      returning = "returnValue")
  public void endpointAfterReturning(JoinPoint p, Object returnValue)  throws Throwable {
   
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    System.out.println("REQUEST PAYLOAD = " + mapper.writeValueAsString(p.getArgs()));
    System.out.println("METHOD NAME = " + p.getSignature().getName());
    System.out.println("RESPONSE OBJECT = " + mapper.writeValueAsString(returnValue));   
   
     //CAN NOT UNDERSTAND HOW TO CAPTURE HTTP VERB AND ENDPOINT HERE 
  }

}
```

Could anyone please help here in capturing Http verb and api end point as well ?

Comment: It is hard to reason about your question (other than coming up with a more global solution like 4rpit suggested) if you do not show your target class(es) but only the aspect. Do they maybe have some request information in fields or method parameters? If so, the aspect could access that information. But I would need to see at least one target class first in order to tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the request object and can get the values you required from it

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
                    .getRequest();
```

and use methods available in `HttpServletRequest`

```
request.getParameterMap()
request.getMethod()
request.getRequestURL()
```

Comment: Hi, @4rpit thanks for your response. Can I do this inside the aspect that I mentioned above?

Comment: No problem Joy, yes you can do it.

Comment: Hi @4rpit, could you please show how we do this inside aspect? I cannot understand how can I access request inside aspect?

Comment: Why don't you just try? As you might have noticed, this is a static method call. So where is the problem?

Comment: Sure @kriegaex. Thanks.