# Extracting response body in aspect for Spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I would like to log response body with aspect in my Spring Boot application. As of now, I am doing this as follows:

```
 @Pointcut("within(com.web.rest.*)")
  public void applicationResourcePointcut() {
  }

 
  @AfterReturning(value = ("applicationResourcePointcut()"),
      returning = "returnValue")
  public void endpointAfterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object returnValue)  throws Throwable {
    
    try {
      System.out.println("RESPONSE OBJECT = " + mapper.writeValueAsString(returnValue)); 
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

But here, I am getting full response with Http Status code and other meta data as follows:

```
RESPONSE OBJECT = {"headers":{"Location":["/api/students/de7cc0b7-dcdf-4f2e-bc26-41525064dd55"],"X-ThreatModelSvc-Alert":["Entit ystudent is created with id:de7cc0b7-dcdf-4f2e-bc26-41525064dd55"]},"body":{"id":"de7cc0b7-dcdf-4f2e-bc26-41525064dd55","name":"Test Name","description":"Test Description","lastModifiedBy":"amallik"},"statusCodeValue":201,"statusCode":"CREATED"}
```

Here, I just would like to capture the response body. I cannot understand how to extract just the body from the response.

Comment: This is not an answer but I use this third-party library for this kind of requirement: https://github.com/zalando/logbook Maybe its help.

Comment: @Habil Thanks a ton for your response. If possible, could you please share some code snippet, from where I can take as a reference?

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot just add the dependency and properties in your application.properties like this; logging:
  level:
    org:
      zalando:
        logbook: TRACE

Comment: Thanks. But @Habil is it possible to user logbook as a library and use its functionality to capture the response body inside aspect as mentioned above?

Comment: DOn't. Spring already has request logging filters which you can use for that.

Comment: This is obviously a follow-up for [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64242791/1082681), but with incomplete code, i.e. not showing where you get `mapper` from. The response you print seems to be JSON, so if you don't want to simply follow M. Deinum's advice (which would probably the best), just use a JSON parser and extract what you need. The question how to extract information from JSON seems to imply that you are a programming newbie. Are you?